# how to select dynamic cell based on numeric value

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for the code for selecting cell based on numeric value.

I have constant column name i.e Q and dynamic numeric value in A2 cell which vary every time like 5, 10 or 22.

If **A2** contain 5 then i wanna go to **Q5**
If **A2** contain 99 then i wanna go to **Q99** .

I have tried offset but not succeed. Any suggestion are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
If Range("A2").Value > 0 And Range("A2").Value < Rows.Count + 1 Then
    Range("Q" & Range("A2").Value).Select
End If
End Sub
```